# Error Acessing Remote SharePoint 2010 sites within same network from .NET 3.5 Windows Application

Tags: powershell, spsite

We have been working on a .NET Windows Application for doing Admin tasks and some validation in SharePoint 2010 , since the tool needs to have the functionality to do a site backup and restore I have used Sharepoint Server Object model.

The tool works perfectly fine when the Site collection and the Tool resides on the same server , But `SPSite()` is throwing exception when I give a remote URL which is within the same network. This URL can be browsed from the Browser.

> Exception :
>
> The Web application at  " SiteURL" could not be found. Verify that you
>   have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing
>   content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL
>   mapping to the intended application.

I did see a lot of queries on this issue in many blogs/communities and have implemented all the solutions mentioned . ie

1. target platform os x64/All CPU
2. Framework changed to 3.5
3. given the following permission to the user running the tool

1.The user is a server farm administrator.
2.The user has Read and Write permissions on the content database(especially the application where site is residing) , config database , admin db.
3.The user is a site collection administrator.
4.The user has permissions to access the SharePoint 2010 site through which the code iterates.
Still I am get the same Error . Please let me know if am missing something else and whether some config changes needs to be made at IIS level or something?

Neither ULS logs not IIS is logging any error.

Does `SPsite()` support connecting to remote sites within same network?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the server object model your scope is limited to the current farm you are on.

If you want to do anything on a remote farm you could use CSOM (Client Side Object Model). This was introduced in SharePoint 2010 and enhanced a great lot in SP2013.

Alternatives to CSOM are the REST interface or using the Web services.
Your choice would depend on exactly what you need to imlement.

Some links to the mentioned tecnologies:

- [CSOM reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Using CSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx)
- [Implementing CSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521585%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Using REST interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)
- [Implementing REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521583%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [ASP.NET web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979690%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Anders for the Reply. I had to do sitebackup/restore opertaions as a part of my tool that is the reason why i did not opt for CSOM or Webservices which does not support admin operations . So I was just exploring the chance of executing the tool from any sharepoint machine in a network.                                                    Thanks alot for the Reply and Suggestion. !