# SharePoint2010: Console application when run remotely unable to access SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In a console application (.exe) I have below line that opens a site.

```
 site = new SPSite(targetServerURL);
 web = site.OpenWeb();
```

I am running exe using PowerShell as below from a non-SharePoint machine as below:-

```
$securePassword= ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -force

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\username",$securePassword)

Invoke-Command -Authentication credssp -Credential $cred -ComputerName machineA.FQDN.com `
-ScriptBlock { & 'c:\Test\MI_PORTAL_2_Demo\Installe.exe'}
```

It throws below exception:

The Web application at http://mysite.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly.

The console application is configured to use .net framework 3.5, Any CPU.

I can access the site(URL) locally. So site exists. PowerShell remoting is enables on all machines involved. And Sharepoint2010 farm is configured with kereberos.

Any idea why this error is thrown when executing it remotely?

Comment: did you try to access site using the pwoershell without exe....get-spsite?

Comment: may be this helps you http://debugmode.net/2010/11/14/the-web-application-could-not-be-found-verify-that-you-have-typed-the-url-correctly-error-sharepoint-2010-object-model/

Comment: Thanks for the reply I looked at that link and I verified that my setup matches it but still seeing this problem when executing remotely

Comment: similary issue but different thought :http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87138/error-acessing-remote-sharepoint-2010-sites-within-same-network-from-net-3-5-wi

Comment: Is this the double-hop issue? Can you open a remote PowerShell session and access the farm? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/26/powershell-remoting-for-sharepoint.aspx.